# Should I avoid using top-level variables in module?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I'm writing code with React, and I'm trying to move some logics to modules, but I'm confused.

I have been writing modules like following lines.

```
// fooModule.js
let count = 0

export function countUp() {
    count += 1
}

export function getCount() {
    return count
}
```

This ***count*** variable can't be access from outer module as expected.

However, I noticed this variable status is keeping, 
When I twice importing this module,
the variable status has shared in both.

So, Should I change to following?

```
// fooModule.js
export function countUp(count) {
    return count + 1
}

// someClass.js
import { countUp } from './fooModule.js'

const count = 0
const newCount = countUp(count)
```

Thanks.

Add: Thank you for many replies in a short time!
I fixed wrong sample code.

Comment: you could export a class and create instances if you want to keep state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second code won't work, because `count` is not in scope in `fooModule`, because you created it in `someClass`. If you want each importer of `fooModule` to have a separate binding for `count`, one option would be to export a *function* that, when called, creates a `count` variable, and returns a function that increments it and returns the new count:

```
// fooModule.js
export function makeCount() {
  let count = 0;
  return () => {
    count++;
    return count;
  };
}

// someClass.js
import { makeCount } from './fooModule.js';
const counter = makeCount();
console.log(counter()); // 1
console.log(counter()); // 2
```

Or, with generators:

```
// fooModule.js
function* makeCount() {
  let count = 0;
  while (true) {
    count++;
    yield count;
  }
}

// someClass.js
const counter = makeCount();
console.log(counter.next().value); // 1
console.log(counter.next().value); // 2
```

(you could also use `return ++count` instead of `count++; return count;` in both codes above, but that's a bit harder to read IMO)

Comment: Or maybe a class `new Counter()`, I know it works around the problem but if I'm going to create something that counts its own state, I like using class syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`require` imports the target script once. Subsequent calls to require for that script will return the result of the first require call for that script. This is why it is OK to use circular dependencies, otherwise a circular dependency would result in an infinite loop.

What this means is that if you want separate instances, you should make a thing that makes those instances, then export *that* thing. Some of the things that make instances of things are:

- Classes,
- Constructors,
- Factory functions, etc

```js
// fooModule.js
export class Counter {
  constructor(count = 0) {
    this.count = count
  }
  countUp() {
    return ++this.count
  }
}

// index.js
const counterA = new Counter(1)
console.log(counterA.countUp()) // 2

const counterB = new Counter(0)
console.log(counterB.countUp()) // 1
```